# como recibir un dato como string api laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola que tal ? estoy trabajando con laravel y necesito recibir un nombre de documento, cuando le coloco espacios "nombre documento" me envía un error 400, pero cuando le ingreso un valor "nombredocumento" todo junto si puedo recibir los datos, como podría modificar la recepcion de los datos para que me permita recibir un dato con espacios desde postman?

[image: nombre con espacios]

[image: nombre sin espacios]

metodo del controlador que recibe el dato

```
public function nombreFuncion(Request $req)
{
 $nombre = $req->input("nombre_doc");
 $gd->setNombreDocumento($nombre);
 try {
        $folio = $gd->generarFolio();
        return response()->json(
               $folio
        );
```

metodo del modelo

```
  public function generarFolio()
{
    $filter = [
        'sistema' => $this->getSistema(),
        'tipo_doc' => $this->getTipoDocumento(),
        'oficina' => $this->getOficina(),
        'departamento' => $this->getDepartamento(),
        'nombre_doc' => $this->getNombreDocumento(),
        'transparencia' => $this->getTransparencia(),
    ];

    $url = $this->getUri() . '?data=' . (string) 
    json_encode($filter);
    SysLogger::info("Request URI", print_r($url, true));

    $header = [ 
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Token ".$this->auth->getToken(),
        "Cookie: ".$this->auth->getCookie()
    ];
    SysLogger::info("Headers to be sent", print_r($header, true));
    
    $response = Page::post($url, [], '', $header);
    print_r($response);
    SysLogger::info("Full response", print_r($response, true));

    $body = json_decode($response['body']);
    // print_r($body);
    SysLogger::info("Body", print_r($body, true));

    
    return $body;
   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A continuación te muestro un ejemplo que te permite enviar contenido y manejarlo como cualquier tipo sin problema:

```
public function registerUser (Request $request)
    {
    //Recogemos los datos que vienen del formulario
    $data = $request->input();
    
    $vld = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:100','unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
    ]);
    

    //Validamos si hay algún error en los datos y lo retornamos
    if ($vld->fails()) {
        $response['message'] = $vld->errors()->first(); 
        return Response::json($response);
    }
    
    //Hacemos cualquier lógica que necesitemos, en este ejemplo crear un usuario
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
    $user->save();
}
```

Esto debería permitirte recibir cualquier contenido proveniente de un formulario, espero haberte ayudado.